# Searching in array returns only the first result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to search in an array and find specific objects based on their category.

But when I run my code, I only get one result. but in the example below, I should have two results because the `cat 2` exists in two of the objects!

This is what I have:

```js
var storedArray = [{
 "title": "test title 1",
 "date_added": "2018-09-26",
 "url": "someurl.com",
 "filename": "file 1",
 "category": "cat 1"
}, {
 "title": "test title 2",
 "date_added": "2018-10-25",
 "url": "someurl.com",
 "filename": "file 2",
 "category": "cat 2"
},{
 "title": "test title 3",
 "date_added": "2018-10-25",
 "url": "someurl.com",
 "filename": "file 3",
 "category": "cat 2"
}];

var result = storedArray.find( audio => audio.category === 'cat 2' );

console.log(result);
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: you don't need jquery!

Comment: "The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

From the above, you have to use `filter()` to get the expected result:

```js
var storedArray = [{
 "title": "test title 1",
 "date_added": "2018-09-26",
 "url": "someurl.com",
 "filename": "file 1",
 "category": "cat 1"
}, {
 "title": "test title 2",
 "date_added": "2018-10-25",
 "url": "someurl.com",
 "filename": "file 2",
 "category": "cat 2"
},{
 "title": "test title 3",
 "date_added": "2018-10-25",
 "url": "someurl.com",
 "filename": "file 3",
 "category": "cat 2"
}];

var result = storedArray.filter( audio => audio.category === 'cat 2' );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first element found. You are looking for [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Answer (score 0):

From the MDN documentation on find...

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Key word: first.

Comment: And what's the solution?

Comment: Use filter. Filter returns an array populated by every result, from the original array, that returns true in your callback function. storedArray.filter(obj => obj.category === 'cat 2);

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using `.find()` is returning only the first record that matches the condition, this is why you are getting only 1 result.